# Shankar Monopole belonging to the class $-1$ of $\pi_3(\mathbb{R}P^3)$

Tags: homotopy-theory, mathematical-physics, higher-homotopy-groups

I am having a lot of trouble trying to understand how the classes of homotopy groups relate to point-defects in physics (and how they can be used/represent in general). This is a problem from Nakahara's textbook on geometry and topology in physics, but is NOT homework; I just want to learn homotopy theory in physics.

In Nakahara's text, he shows how the Shankar monopole comes about by stating, "[since we have] compactified $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $S^3$...[I believe this means there is order parameter $\psi$ such that $\psi:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow S^3$]...the texture is classified by the third homotopy group of the real projective plane, $\pi_3(\mathbb{R}P^3)\cong\mathbb{Z}$." Now, I know that the real-projective plane is homeomorphic to a sphere, so finding the spheres homotopy group is how to proceed, namely in this case, $\pi_3(\mathbb{R}P^3)=\pi_3(S^3)=\pi_3(SO(3))$. Now, by the last equality, we can take a vector $\Omega(r) = \theta n$ where $n$ is an axis in $S^3$. Since $\Omega(r)$ traces out a disc, $D^3$, there are antipodal point that are the same rotation (this is how the relation between the $S^n$ and $\mathbb{R}P^n$ works (as far as I can understand). But, physically, Shankar decided to write the vector as $\Omega(r) = \frac{\mathbb{r}}{r}\cdot f(r)$ where $f(r)$ can take values of $2\pi$ for $r=0$  or $0$ for $r\rightarrow \infty$.

The trouble of understanding for me though comes from the next part in Nakahara's text where he says that, "as we scan the whole space, $\Omega(r)$ sweeps $SO(3)$ twice [as I described above], and this texture corresponds to class $1$ of $\pi_3(SO(3)\cong\mathbb{Z}$."

Now, how does this relate to class $1$ of $\pi_3(SO(3))$?? I understand that if $\pi_3(SO(3))\cong\mathbb{Z}$ then there are an infinite number of homotopy classes since $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite. From a group perspective, this means there is one generator that creates the group of homotopy classes, but how this relates back to defining a vector $v(r)$ and then describing (and better yet drawing) a texture that relates to $-1$ of the same group, is where I am stuck.

I may be reading to fast over definitions and am not fully comprehending what they mean (this could completely be the case), or missing the mark entirely. Anything helps, thanks. (Also put this on the physics stack exchange but I feel this is more mathematical).

For clarity, the drawing/sketch I mentioned is the following image from page 167, figure 4.32 of Nakahara's text: [image: Shankar Monopole]